# How to achieve space between property column wise when using MUI grid?

Tags: css, material-ui

How can we achieve space-between  when elements are in column wise when using MUI Grid. Read about some answers that by giving flex:1 and height:100% we could achieve. But as I am using MUI Grid I want to know how this could be achieved in grid instead of flex? Attaching the code sandbox, where I need separation between two buttons as I am trying to show the second button in bottom.

https://codesandbox.io/s/boxsx-material-demo-forked-392dfl?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: will spacing work for you?

Comment: If you want to fix something at the end then using grid will not work. `grid`  will not serve your purpose you have to assign width to middle component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `height` to the `container` grid and it will serve your purpose. Your code is right but if you want to put `button` at the bottom your `div`  then it should take that much space so that it can place it.

```
      <Grid
         container
         direction="column"
        style={{ height: "90vh" }}
         justifyContent="space-between"
         alignItems="center"
         
       >
```

Answer (score 0):

Use gap property for spacing

[forked codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boxsx-material-demo-forked-jd2vm0)

Comment: Gap property I am aware of .But I need the second button to be bottom of page.For example if I have 2 elements 1&2, 1 should be there at top and 2 at bottom of page

Comment: @antoclinton Try this https://codesandbox.io/s/boxsx-material-demo-forked-jd2vm0?file=/index.tsx